# How to compare 2 number?

Tags: assembly

i am writing a program that compare 2 numbers that have been defined in data segment. 
i define them like this

```
Dseg SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'data'
NUM1 DW 1 ; num1 = 1
NUM2 DW 2 ; num2 = 2
MAX DW ?  ; variable to save the max number
MIN DW ?  ; variable to save the min number
Dseg ENDS 


Cseg SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'code'
    ASSUME  CS : Cseg , DS : Dseg , SS : Sseg , ES : NOTHING
    ORG 100H

    Mov AX , Dseg
    Mov DS , AX

    Mov AX , NUM1 ; move num1 to AX   
    CMP AX , NUM2 ; compare num1 with num2
    JAE MAX1      ; jump if num1 > num2

    Mov AX  , NUM2; ax = num2
    Mov MAX , AX  ; max = ax
    Mov AX  , NUM1; ax = num1
    Mov MIN , AX  ; min = ax
    JMP ENDPROG 

MAX1 :
    Mov AX  , NUM1; ax = num1
    Mov MAX , AX  ; max = ax
    Mov AX  , NUM2; ax = num2
    Mov MIN , AX  ; min = ax    
    JMP ENDPROG 

ENDPROG :  
    ;..............


    Mov AX , 4c00H
    INT 21H 


    Cseg ENDS

    END
```

but the jump orders does not work well! and it stuck at ENDPROG label.
i want to know why is that?
what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you mean by _"the jump orders does not work well"_?

Comment: the jmp or jae does not work.  it is like there is no jump order.

Comment: How are you testing that the jumps don't work? Single-step in a debugger?

Comment: @Jongware yeah, in emu8086

Comment: And during debugging you see `ax` gets loaded with the correct value?

Comment: @Jongware no , the values are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

`mov ax, NUM1` loads `ax` with the address of `NUM1`. You should use `mov ax, [NUM1]`, and the same for all other operations that access variables.

Comment: The code in the question looks like it was written for TASM or MASM. With those assemblers, `mov ax,NUM1` and `mov ax,[NUM1]` mean the same thing.

Comment: Ouch. Probably *because* it's such a frequent mistake... If the OP indeed uses one of these, I'll delete this answer!